# Training the surrogate model Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: python

Training the surrogate model

Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Training the surrogate model

Segmentation fault (core dumped)
尝试了解决方案1:conda install ipykernel --update-deps --force-reinstall 不行

解决方案2：pip install pywin32==228dodou'b都不行